# Referencing parent class in CoffeeScript from a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeScript and I was wondering if there's a way of writing the following piece of code without referencing the global variable app:

```
class App 

    constructor: ->
        @ui = ui.init()
        $('#content-holder a[rel!=dialog]').live 'click', ->
            link = $(@).attr 'href'
            app.loadUrl link
            return false

    loadUrl: (href) ->
        # ...

app = new App()
```

Using the fat arrow doesn't work, as then I lose reference to the jQuery object, i.e.

```
class App   
    constructor: ->
        @ui = ui.init()
        $('#content-holder a[rel!=dialog]').live 'click', =>
            # @ now references App
            link = $(@).attr 'href'
            this.loadUrl link
            return false

    loadUrl: (href) ->
        # ...
```

The first piece of code works, but I want to get rid of the global variable if possible :-)

Cheers,
Gaz.

Comment: Have you tried `@loadUrl link` instead of `this.loadUrl`  If that doesn't work, please post the compiled javascript.

Comment: @something is just a syntactic sugar for this.something, afaik

Comment: That won't work, because @ (this) will be referencing the anonymous callback function.

Comment: @Gaz I was just copying from this http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow  I read it as using the fat arrow binds the context to the value of this prior to entering the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your click handler gets an event passed in... so you can get the best of both worlds with the "fat arrow" without the need to also reference `self` :

```
constructor: ->
    @ui = ui.init()
    $('#content-holder a[rel!=dialog]').live 'click', (e) =>
        link = $(e.target).attr 'href'
        @loadUrl link
        return false
```

Comment: Actually I had the 'fat' arrow, but could not get the element I clicked on =) thx

Answer (score 6):

Well, CS is just a higher-level syntax for JS.

In JS `this` can only reference a single object.

The fat arrow uses closure to make `this` equal to a higher level `this`, nothing more, and that's why it overrides `this` in a callback's scope

The plain arrow, in contrary, is just a `function` alias, and that's why `this` is a DOM element in the first case.

Finally, `@something` is trivially translated to `this.something`, and does nothing more.

So, my opinion - your best choice is really doing `self = @` before the binding.

Comment: Thanks Guard. I thought CoffeeScript might have something magical that might be able to get around littering self = @ all over the place :-)

Comment: @Gaz Actually, there is a better way.  See my response.

Comment: +1 for the "fat arrow uses closure to make this equal to a higher level this" as it's first time I understood the significance after 3 days learning CS!